# How to open multiple tabbed files in vim, each at a specified line?

Tags: linux, command-line, vim

Using vim I can open multiple tabbed files using the -p switch:

```
$ vim -p file1 file2 file3
```

Using vim I can open a file at a particular line:

```
$ vim file1 +123
```

How can I open multiple files in tabs, each at their own distinct line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will do it: `vim +123 file1 +"tabnew +20 file2"`

As mentioned in the comments, you can continue adding files in using the same syntax:

`vim +123 file1 +"tabnew +20 file2" +"tabnew +40 file3" +"tabnew +10 file4"`

user74094 made the point that unfortunately this opens to the last tab rather than the first. This can be fixed with the addition of *tabfirst* as such:

`vim +123 file1 +"tabnew +20 file2" +tabfirst`

For anyone who doesn't understand, a + means vim executes a new command. So this is essentially saying, "open vim to line 123 on file1, then open a new tab with file2 to line 20, then switch to the first tab"

Original answer/research taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148397/vim-open-multiples-files-on-different-lines).

Comment: Thanks. A bit verbose; and it opens on the rightmost file rather than the leftmost with -p; but I suppose it gets the job done!

Comment: By the way, 3 files would look like this: `vim +123 file1 +"tabnew +456 file2" +"tabnew +789 file3"`

Comment: You could always add +tabprev after each file. It gets a bit messy, although I'm sure you could write a bash script that would make it cleaner and more usable:

`vim +123 file1 +"tabnew +20 file2" +tabprev

Comment: You could also use +tabfirst. I've updated my answer to reflect this.